# validar campos de un form con javascript para contraseñas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

***Objetivo:*** Hacer que cambien de color el texto de arriba del input cuando sean distinta o iguales las contraseñas digitadas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trato de validar que la nueva contraseña y la repetición de la misma, al coincidir me cambien de color las letras a verde, pero solo logro que cambien a rojo si no son iguales.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function ($) {
        var newp = $('#npass').val();
        $('#rnpass').keyup(function () {
            var v = $('#rnpass').val();
            if(v == '' || v != newp){
                $('#rnp').addClass('text-danger');
            }else{
                if(v != '' || v == newp){
                    $('#rnp').removeClass('text-danger');
                    $('#rnp').addClass('text-success');
                }
            }
        });
    }(jQuery));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="Persona" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label id="cp">Current password*</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Current password*" name="pass" required/>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label><span id="np">New password*</span></label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="New password*" name="npass" id="npass" required />
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label><span id="rnp">Repeat new password*</span></label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Repeat new password*" name="rnpass" id="rnpass" required />
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd">Update</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('keyup','#foo, #bar',function(){
    var foo = $('#foo').val().trim();
    var bar = $('#bar').val().trim();
    if( !foo || !bar || foo == '' || bar == '' ){
      $('#poo').removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-danger').text('Las contraseñas no coinciden');
    }
    
    else{
      if( foo !== bar ){
        $('#poo').removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-danger').text('Las contraseñas no coinciden');
      }
      
      else{
      $('#poo').removeClass('text-danger').addClass('text-success').text('Las contraseñas si coinciden');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<label id="poo"></label><br>
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="foo">
<label>Repite el password</label><br>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="bar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar el evento onchange para llamar la funcion a cada cambio hecho en el input, en mi ejemplo solo esta para el campo de repetir campo pero puedes hacerlo en ambos.

```
function validar() {

    var primerInput = document.getElementById("primero").value;
    var segundoInput = document.getElementById("segundo").value;


    if(primerInput === segundoInput)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```